# Python regex and string replacement

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert strings in Python such as:

```
string = 'void demofun(double* output, double db4nsfy[], double VdSGV[], int length)'
```

into

```
wrapper = 'void demofun(ref double output, double[] db4nsfy, double[] VdSGV, int length)'
```

Now for most cases, I'm able to use a trivial combination of `while`, `string.find()` and `string.replace()` to do this because I don't need to meddle with the variable names (such as `output` or `length`), but what I can't figure out is replacing these strings:

`double db4nsfy[]` --> `double[] db4nsfy`

`double[] VdSGV` --> `double[] VdSGV`

How should I do this? I know I will find my answer with some RTFM of regex in Python, but I'm hoping to start with a practical example.

Comment: I'm probably wrong - but aren't their better ways instead of manipulating the source code of co-oping between C/C++ and C# ?

Comment: Hm, it'd be annoying if a tool like this already existed but I'd be even happier if it did. I have a lot of Fortran/C numerical routines that I need to interop and they get thrown into many separate .cs source files because of the various things I need done (e.g. testing their speeds against my pure C# implementations). I figured the usage was too specialized but simple enough that a proper tool didn't exist. Had to come up with my own pariah method of indicating which arguments to marshal with the [In] and [Out] attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+) (\w+)\[\]', r'\1[] \2', string)
    'void demofun(double* output, double[] db4nsfy, double[] VdSGV, int length)'
```

- `(\w+) (\w+)\[\]` matches two "words" wrapped in capturing groups and brackets.
- `\1` and `\2` refer to the stuff captured by those groups.

Comment: Awesome! Explains the solution I needed. Could you suggest the benefits that I'd gain from using something like AStyle in this particular instance? Be brutally honest ;)

Comment: @ephedyn: Probably ease of use and versatility. Regex is clunky and wasn't made specifically to beautify source files.

Comment: I see. I'm actually using Python to generate C# wrappers for a bunch of Fortran/C subroutines. I'll pick up a code formatter and try it out on the routines themselves, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

verbose, but without regex and handles both pointer and arrays(and also without regex):

```
def new_arguments(func_string):
    def argument_replace(arguments):
        new_arguments = []
        for argument in arguments.split(', '):
            typ, var = argument.split()
            if typ.endswith('*'):
                typ = 'ref ' + typ.replace('*', '')
            if var.endswith('[]'):
                var = var.replace('[]', '')
                typ += '[]'
            new_arguments.append(' '.join([typ, var]))
        return ', '.join(new_arguments)

    func_name = func_string[:func_string.index('(')]
    arguments = func_string[func_string.index('(')+1:func_string.index(')')]

    return ''.join((func_name, '(', argument_replace(arguments), ')'))

string = 'void demofun(double* output, double db4nsfy[], double VdSGV[], int length)'
print new_arguments(string)
#void demofun(ref double output, double[] db4nsfy, double[] VdSGV, int length)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an intuitive approach without regex.

```
s = 'void demofun(double* output, double db4nsfy[], double VdSGV[], int length)'
s = s.split()
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i][-3:] == '[],':
        s[i] = s[i][:-3] + ','
        s[i-1] = s[i-1] + '[]'
    elif s[i][-3:] == '[])':
        s[i] = s[i][:-3] + ')'
        s[i-1] = s[i-1] + '[]'
s = ' '.join(s)
print s
# void demofun(double* output, double[] db4nsfy, double[] VdSGV, int length)
```